# parsivar : NLTK was unable to find the java file

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I was working with parsivar (a Persian NLP library based on nltk) with this script:

```
from parsivar import Normalizer
from parsivar import Tokenizer
my_normalizer = Normalizer()
my_tokenizer = Tokenizer()
from parsivar import FindStems
my_stemmer = FindStems()
from parsivar import POSTagger
my_tagger = POSTagger(tagging_model="wapiti")
```

and I had a problem with JAVAHOME!

also I tried this:

```
import os
java_path = "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_281/bin/java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
```

but still I have this problem:

```
LookupError: 

===========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the java file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the JAVAHOME environment variable.
===========================================================================
```

There was no problem running this code on Ubuntu, but this is the case when I'm using Windows.

Comment: Hi, could you fix problem?

Comment: @NASRIN the problem is already fixed, check the answers

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with Java direction in `internals.py` file in nltk library, I added some lines and I it worked:

```
java_path = "C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_281/bin/java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
def config_java(bin=java_path, options=None, verbose=False):
...
```

it was `config_java(bin=None, options=None, verbose=False)` before.